# Reapply JS Prototype functions after deserialization

Tags: javascript, casting

Given the following code:

```
function Person(firstName, lastName) {
    this.FirstName = firstName;
    this.LastName = lastName;
}

Person.prototype.showFullName = function() {
    return this.FirstName + " " + this.LastName;
};

var person = new Person("xx", "xxxx");
var jsonString = JSON.stringify(person);

var thePerson = JSON.parse(jsonString);
```

My goal here would be to be able to call "showFullName" on thePerson. While I understand that JS does not really have objects, it must have some way of being able to say something should be treated a certain way, like casting `thePerson` to a `Person`.

Comment: (It's more parse than cast, as I see it)

Comment: Javascript *does* have objects--it's completely object-oriented. It just doesn't have a strongly-enforced typing system, so you can call anything on anything and not know you have a problem until later. But I think gdoron is probably correct about not preserving methods. Have you written your JSON string to output?

Comment: You can do it if the implementation supports the non-standard `__proto__` property. `thePerson.__proto__ = Person.prototype`.

Comment: Thanks to Dan for the working answer. I will probably end up yanking JQuery extend method. This is going to happen as part of a caching process, and I would like the cache to be as reusable as possible.

Comment: @xximjasonxx: Don't bother yanking `extend`. Just do `for(p in parsed) thePerson[p] = parsed[p];`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To my knowledge the best way to do this is to construct a vanilla object first and then plop the data onto it using something like jQuery's [extend](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/), ie.

```
var thePerson = new Person(); // and make sure the constructor gracefully handles no arguments
jQuery.extend(thePerson, JSON.parse(stringData));
```

As mentioned below, you don't need to use `extend` if you're only creating a shallow copy, which you are here. You can just loop through the properties of the parsed data and copy them onto your target object.

Comment: Friggin awesome!!! This works.  While I hate making my cache reliant on JQuery, this does work.  As soon as I can accept the answer, I will

Comment: Is there anything in native JS that is similar to this? Just out of curiousity

Comment: great, except the question is about javascript, not jquery.  Not everyone uses jquery.

Comment: No, but take a look at the jQuery sources if you're curious - it's actually not all that complex.

Comment: @hvgotcodes jQuery is not its own language, and `extend` in particular is a self contained function, its logic is simple enough. Other libraries should have similar functions.

Comment: I would use `Object.create(Person.prototype)` to avoid running the constructor. And you don't need jQuery to make a shallow copy of object properties. Just use a `for-in` loop. Doesn't make sense to load jQuery (or any library) for a simple copy.

Comment: I have spent more time waiting to accept the language then it took to answer the question

Comment: Mean t to say answer there :)

Answer (score 2):

**It's impossible**.

You can't convert a a JSON string to an object with it's previous methods.

Answer (score 2):

Like most things that have language constructs in other languages, even though you can't do it directly, there's a way around it in Javascript. Just set up your object to accept all the data it exposes as a constructor:

```
var data = JSON.parse(jsonString);
var person = new Person(data);
```

from scratch:

```
var person = new Person({ FirstName: "xx", LastName: "xxx"});
```

(nb - you could use `$.extend` or the like to update an existing instance instead - but generally it's preferable to use the constructor so you have control over the handling of the object that gets passed in; for example you may want to ignore all except certain properties of the object that's passed in).

Answer (score 0):

> While I understand that JS does not really have objects, it must have
>   some way of being able to say something should be treated a certain
>   way.

Not correct.  There are lots of objects in JS; Functions themselves are objects.  AFAIK the only things that are NOT objects are primitive types.  Maybe what you mean to say is that Javascript has no notion of a **class**.  That would be correct, as JS uses prototypal inheritance.

In the general sense, casting makes no sense in JS.  If you do

`x.someMethod()`

someMethod will fire if it is defined on `x`, no matter what type `x` is.  It's called duck typing.

`JSON.parse` creates an `object literal`.  The best you can do is create a constructor that takes an object literal an initializes the values of your instance.

Comment: It might just be my personal preference, but I do not count the "soft objects" in JS as objects, but that is likely my bias toward real OO languages showing

Comment: js is a real OO language.  Just because you only understand OO in the context of classical inheritance doesn't mean there aren't other things out there.  What do you mean by "soft objects"?  JS has real objects.

Comment: Another time for that debate :)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a kind of wrapper class which you can feed an object to the constructor and it will set each property as a property of that object. You could make this a 'baseclass' so you can use it for all kind of objects. That way, you would only have to create a new instance of the class that 'inherits' from that baseclass and feed it with you object. Kind of like models as used in http://backbonejs.org/